# Geoserver WFS-T Insert error (ORA-22816) when using layers based on database views i.c. with sequence numbering for ID's

Tags: oracle11g, geoserver

We are working on a Frontend application, which adds new data to layers of GeoServer. The Frontend is using WFS-T Insert calls to add this data. We use views for these layers in GeoServer, to do some additional handling. The views we use are database views thus created on our Oracle database itself (e.g. we do not use the SQL Views of GeoServer). These layers based on views work all fine (solution applied with a disabled “primary key” for the view as described elsewhere on the internet).

The views we use contain an unique ID which is the unique ID of the “principal” table which is used in the view. For the unique creation of the ID’s for the “principal” table we chose to have the creation of this ID to be done by a sequence defined in Oracle. For using this sequence within GeoServer you can provide this “metadata” as indicated by the documentation: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html

This solutions works fine, except when you use an (insert) trigger on the database view.

*CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OUR_VIEW_TRG
instead of insert or update or delete on vw_our_view
for each row…*

If we perform a WFS-T insert call this results in the following exception:

> org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Error performing insert:
>   Error inserting features Error performing insert: Error inserting
>   features Error inserting features ORA-22816: unsupported feature with
>   RETURNING clause

Without indicating GeoServer to use the sequence we get returned a feature ID, which will not correspond with our sequence numbering on the ID of the table (GeoServer simply returns the number of rows of the table, plus one). This results in an undesired situation where we have an incorrect ID at the Frontend after an WFS-T insert, only after a refresh of the browser the correct ID is being fetched.

Does anybody know if there is a way to make this work, e.g. for our customer changing the GeoServer code ourselves, and thus create our “own” version of GeoServer is no option. Stop using the views would imply extra WFS-T insert calls from our FrontEnd Application.

Comment: GeoServer is just reporting the Oracle error, you need to fix that trigger so it works on normal inserts before trying it in GeoServer.

Comment: Thanks Ian, to be sure it is not the trigger we already tried it with a "harmless" trigger.